# How to code in Excel VBA for the following purpose?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Workbook with 4 sheets in my hand. Each sheet contains daily data for a stock. Each sheet contains 3 columns: the first column lists "Date": 1/6/04 - 6/20/14. The 2nd column is the daily return of this stock recorded on each day. The 3rd column is the daily volume of this stock.

I want to compile the data in the four sheets to just one sheet with 9 columns: 1st column is the date. 2nd&3rd columns contain the return & volume of the 1st stock; 4th&5th columns have the return & volume of the 2nd stock; 6th&7th for the 3rd stock and 8th & 9th for the last stock. In other words, the data of the four stocks would be listed on the same sheet by "Date".

One problem: the first stock has 2692 trading days recorded, yet the 2nd has only 2638 trading days. The 3rd and 4th stocks both have 2633 days recorded. And, for example, on 5/13/2009, only the 1st and the 4th stocks were traded (with data available), but the 2nd and 3rd stocks do not have data, so 5/13/2009 is not included in the 2nd and 3rd sheet of the raw data file. But I want this date to be included in my final (compiled) data sheet because on this day, at least one stock is available.

Eventually, I wish my final sheet to have all the dates when any stocks were traded. For all the missing data (or missing spots), I wish the cells to be filled with NaN.

How can I achieve this in excel VBA/Macro? I also use R so any coding advice with R on this problem would also help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an outline (I hope the SO police don't shoot me).
Can you get started with this?

```
Sub Main()
  do ' this is the outer loop
    for sheet = 1 to 4
      get the lowest unselected date
    next sheet
    if all sheets are done, then exit sub    
    for sheet = 1 to 4
      get either data or NaN for the selected date
    next sheet
  loop
End Sub
```

EDIT: ' (I don't know what "on hold" does) This should be a good model for using arrays. (I'll do anything for 15 points.) I've made many assumptions. You don't need to change dates into integers to compare.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
  Dim iSheet&, aSheets(2) As Worksheet, Outsheet As Worksheet
  Dim iRow&(2), iLastRow&(2), outRow&, iCol1&, iCol2&, Date1$, selectedDate$
  Set aSheets(1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("adam")
  Set aSheets(2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("bill")
  Set Outsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("zack")
  iLastRow(1) = 3: iLastRow(2) = 4 ' ending rows
  iRow(1) = 1: iRow(2) = 1 ' starting rows
  outRow = 1
  Do ' this is the outer loop
    selectedDate = "12/31/9999" ' starting date (high)
    For iSheet = 1 To 2
      If iRow(iSheet) <= iLastRow(iSheet) Then
        Date1 = aSheets(iSheet).Cells(iRow(iSheet), 1)
        If Date1 < selectedDate Then selectedDate = Date1
      End If
    Next iSheet
    If selectedDate = "12/31/9999" Then Exit Sub ' no more
    Outsheet.cells(outRow, 1) = selectedDate
    For iSheet = 1 To 2
      iCol1 = iSheet * 2 ' output columns
      iCol2 = iCol1 + 1
      If iRow(iSheet) <= iLastRow(iSheet) Then
        Date1 = aSheets(iSheet).Cells(iRow(iSheet), 1)
        If Date1 = selectedDate Then
          Outsheet.Cells(outRow, iCol1) = aSheets(iSheet).Cells(iRow(iSheet), 2)
          Outsheet.Cells(outRow, iCol2) = aSheets(iSheet).Cells(iRow(iSheet), 3)
          iRow(iSheet) = iRow(iSheet) + 1 ' next row
        Else
          Outsheet.Cells(outRow, iCol1) = "na"
          Outsheet.Cells(outRow, iCol2) = "na"
        End If
      End If
    Next iSheet
    outRow = outRow + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @dcromley I completely understand the logic of your outline. I'm a novice for excel vba, could you show me how to write the code for "get the lowest unselected date for sheet 1 to 4"? I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Also, do I need to change the dates into integer format? Or excel could tell which date is the lowest?